# SharePoint 2013 app requesting data from external web service with same credentials

Tags: api, sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2013, csom

I've been looking at this so long now that I think I'm probably missing something obvious.  My scenario is this.

I have a SharePoint 2013 app which needs to pull data from a set of web services (not SharePoint hosted) to populate the application.  Because the SharePoint server and API server are hosted in the same domain and authenticate against the same AD server, what I would like is for the user to sign in to SharePoint and then use the same credentials to make the request to the API server.  It's a SharePoint hosted app, so the request needs to be made via JavaScript (well, using jQuery).

I'm guessing that this is possible, but what's the best way to look at implementing it.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm in the same situation finding this first step which obviously should be easy extremely difficult. I end up finding examples on how to use the Sharepoint JS API but not other services.

Comment: We never did I'm afraid.  Actually we switched completely away from using SP2013 and moved to ASP.NET MVC5 and changed to using ADFS 3.  Using SP just became too much of an expensive headache.